# Angular Dependency Injection for Protected Pages

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angular .
I'm trying to create a website with user login. The website will have a welcome page, login/registration and User home. The User home will require authentication.
The folders/files will be

```
root/app.js
root/index.html

root/welcome/welcomeModule.js // welcome module init
root/welcome/js/controller.js
root/welcome/view/welcome.html

root/user/userModule.js // user module init
root/user/js/controller.js
root/user/view/welcome.html
```

I don't want to expose any files inside `root/user/`

1. Assuming that the routes to `root/user/` is protected on the server(nodejs), how do I inject the user related dependencies only after user logs in ?
2. Also as `root/user` is protected, how/where to add `<script/>` for the above dependencies dynamically ? (cannot include in index.html)
3. Or is there a different way to do it ? have two index homes, etc?

Comment: What's the problem in "exposing" these files? They're just static resources, containing code that any AngularJS developer could write. They don't contain sensitive data.

Comment: I guess thats true. Lack of experience in Angular makes me want to protect all the resources that need authentication. 
However after giving it some thought, I figured that I would want a lean login page and not burden the user's network with unnecessary dependencies. Assuming the routes are protected, how can this be done ?